# Помогите правильно написать MySQL-запрос с сортировкой по двум таблицам

Tags: sql, запрос, mysql

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно написать MySQL-запрос.

Есть две таблицы.

```
users:
1. user_id
2. name
3. rating (int)
4. place (int)

subscribes (подписки на пользователей):
1. from_user_id (кто подписался)
2. to_user_id (на кого подписался)
```

Нужно написать запрос, который будет сортировать пользователей по трем параметрам:

1. По рейтингу (rating), чем больше рейтинг, тем выше пользователь
2. По количеству подписчиков, чем больше подписчиков, тем выше пользователь
3. По месту (place), чем выше место (т.е. чем меньше число), тем выше пользователь

Я написал следующий вариант:

```
SELECT subscribes.to_user_id, count(subscribes.to_user_id) as cnt, users.* 
FROM subscribes, users
WHERE users.user_id = subscribes.to_user_id
GROUP BY subscribes.to_user_id
ORDER BY users.rating DESC, cnt DESC, users.place ASC
```

И тут все хорошо, сортировка работает, но есть одна загвоздка. Учитываются только пользователи, у которых есть хотя бы один подписчик, остальные не показываются вообще. Я понимаю, с чем это связано — "`WHERE users.user_id = subscribes.to_user_id`", но как это решить мыслей нет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно изменить запрос таким образом, чтобы учитывались и пользователи без подписчиков. Спасибо.

Comment: Прочтите про предложение LEFT JOIN и используйте его в Вашем запросе.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.rating, users.place
count(subscribes.to_user_id) as cnt
FROM subscribes right join users
on users.user_id = subscribes.to_user_id
GROUP BY users.user_id, users.rating, users.place
ORDER BY users.rating DESC, cnt DESC, users.place ASC
```

[Операции соединения](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_explicit_join_operations.html)